# Problem with UITableViewNavigation, passing of data on segue

Tags: ios, swift

I am failing to pass data from `UITableView` to a `UIViewController`. Have tried several ways but failing. Getting this error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVO)

when I run the project.

See the code below of what I have tried.

```
//Code on the UITableViewController

class ShonaHymnsUITableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var hymns : [Hymns] = Hymns.fetchHymns()

    //MARK: - UItableViewDataSource
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hymns.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hymnCell", for: indexPath) as! HymnsTableViewCell

        let hymn = hymns[indexPath.row]
        cell.hymn = hymn
        return cell
    }

//    MARK: - NAVIGATION
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowHymnDetail", sender: indexPath)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // TODO: Prepare for Hymn Detal segue
        if segue.identifier == "ShowShonaHymnListing" {
            let shonaHymnListingVC = segue.destination as! ShonaHymnsUITableViewController
            shonaHymnListingVC.hymns = hymns

        } else if segue.identifier == "ShowHymnDetail" {

            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let selectedHymn = hymns[(indexPath?.row)!]
            let hymnDetailVC = segue.destination as! ShonaHymnsViewController
               hymnDetailVC.hymn = selectedHymn
            }
    }
}

//Code on the ViewController that I want to receive the data
class ShonaHymnsViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var hymnNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hymnTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hymnDetail: UITextView!

    var hymn: Hymns!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        hymnNumber.text = hymn.hymnNumber
        hymnTitle.text = hymn.hymnTitle
        hymnDetail.text = hymn.hymnDetail

    }

}
```

This is a hymn book application and I expect the full hymn detail to be shown on the recipient view controller. [See image for the setup of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W46ak.png)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse order of

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowHymnDetail", sender: indexPath)
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

for this

```
hymns[(indexPath?.row)!]
```

to have a valid value

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying are should put the self.override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) at the bottom of 
this one: hymns[(indexPath?.row)!]? I have done it and it's still giving the same error.